# HTML onclick pass parameter to javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I'm generating this HTML element:

```
tdSecond.innerHTML += `<select id="train_input" class="custom-select" style="width: 70px; margin-bottom: 10px;" onchange="setAndReload(${data[i]['id']})">
```

So on a change of this select, I want to call setAndReload function with `data[i]['id']` parameter. However, when I do a console log of that parameter in my `setAndReload` function, what I get is this:

`[object HTMLHeadingElement]`

How can I pass that parameter into onclick correctly, so that I get the real string?

`data[i]` is an object, that holds `id` attribute (and that's string). I want to have a string sent as a parameter.

Comment: I'm not really sure how we're supposed to know? Please may you edit the question to include a [mcve]? What is `data` What do you expect it to become inside the string?

Comment: Edited. Data is an array holding a lot of objects.

Comment: Thank you (although, an example of `data` in code form is more useful that a description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to get the selected value in onchange function as parameter you can do something like this:

```js
function myFunction(selectedObject) {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `You selected: ${selectedObject.value} House`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new house from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
  <option value="Tiny">Tiny House</option>
  <option value="Big">Big House</option>
  <option value="Small">Small House</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a new house, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected house.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

The above example gets you the selected value on OnChange event.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You really should use data attributes and delegation

```
document.getElementById("myTable").addEventListener("change",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("custom-select")) {
    setAndReload(tgt.dataset.id,tgt.value)
  }
})
```

using

```
tdSecond.innerHTML += `<select id="train_input" class="custom-select" 
  style="width: 70px; margin-bottom: 10px;" data-id ="${data[i]['id']}")>`
```

I am sure you could use a map on the data array instead of concatenating to innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a single **[event listener](https://eloquentjavascript.net/15_event.html) instead of multiple inline event handlers**, as shown in the following snippet. I wasn't sure exctly what your select element (including its change listener) is intended to do, so I just made it show/hide the corresponding `Train` from the data array.

You can also sometimes avoid headaches (such as more complicated maintenance, and errors resulting from typos)  by **creating DOM elements in JavaScript** and appending them to existing elements, rather than trying to parse complex strings for use by the `innerHTML` method -- so the `addTrainInput` function demonstrates this.  (Compare the "sloppier" code I included that displays each train in the `setAndReload` listener.)

See the in-code comments for further clarification.

```js
// Identifies some DOM elements, and gets the data array
const
  trSecond = document.getElementById("trSecond"),
  output = document.getElementById("output"),
  data = getData();

// Dynamically adds select elements, and shows trains
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  addTrainInput(data[i]["id"]); // Adds each select element
}
setAndReload(); // To show all trains right away

// Calls setAndReload whenever something in trSecond changes
trSecond.addEventListener("change", setAndReload);


// Defines the change listener (which also gets called directly)
function setAndReload(event){

  // B/c we're listening on parent div, checks event's actual target before proceeding
  if(event && !event.target.classList.contains("custom-select")){ 
    return;
  }
  output.innerHTML = ""; // Hides all trains for now
  for(let trainInput of trSecond.children){ // Loops through select elements
    if(trainInput.value == "shown"){

      // Finds matching train in data
      const train = data.find(obj => obj.id == trainInput.dataset.id);

      // Shows the train
      output.innerHTML += train.image + "<br><br>";
    }
  }
}

// Defines a function to add each select elemement
// (The corresponding train is tracked via a `data-id` attribute)
function addTrainInput(trainId){
  
  // Makes the select element (with class and data-id attrubutes)
  trainInput = document.createElement("select");
  trainInput.classList.add("custom-select");
  trainInput.dataset.id = trainId;

  // Makes an option and appends it to the select
  opt1 = document.createElement("option");
  opt1.value = "shown";
  opt1.textContent = trainId + " Shown";
  trainInput.appendChild(opt1);

  // Makes another option and appends it to the select
  opt2 = document.createElement("option");
  opt2.value = "hidden";
  opt2.textContent = trainId + " Hidden";
  trainInput.appendChild(opt2);

  // Finally, adds the select (with its options) to the DOM
  trSecond.appendChild(trainInput);
}

// Just returns our initial data array
function getData(){
  const data = [
    {id: "Train1", image: "&nbsp&nbsp&lt; picture of Train 1 &gt;"},
    {id: "Train2", image: "&nbsp&nbsp&lt; picture of Train 2 &gt;"},
    {id: "Train3", image: "&nbsp&nbsp&lt; picture of Train 3 &gt;"},
  ];
  return data;
}
```

```css
.custom-select { width: 110px; margin-right: 10px; }
#output { margin-top: 25px; font-size: 1.2em; }
```

```html
<div id=trSecond></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```